# Unable to disable default login form from spring security 6.2.1

Tags: spring, authentication, security, default

I use spring security 6.2.1 with spring boot 3.2 to handle login to my web application.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to disable the default login form of spring security.
I want to use my own custom login form but I'm always redirected to the spring default form.

This is my filter :

@Bean

```
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    try {
        http
        // ...
       .httpBasic(httpBasic -> httpBasic.disable())
       .authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeExchange) -> authorizeExchange
             .requestMatchers("/mylogin").permitAll()               
             .anyRequest().permitAll())
       .csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable())
       .formLogin(form -> form.loginPage("/login").permitAll());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return http.build();
```

}

I enter http://127.0.0.1:8080/mylogin and I expect to be redirected to my custom page and not the default one  !!!

I followed this page to use my custom login page but I always see the default one.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html

Here are my logs

```
2024-01-03 11:30:35.602 | DEBUG | parallel-1 | WebSessionServerRequestCache:83 |  | Request added to WebSession: '/mylogin'
2024-01-03 11:30:35.603 | DEBUG | parallel-1 | DefaultServerRedirectStrategy:54 |  | Redirecting to '/login'
2024-01-03 11:30:35.638 | DEBUG | http-nio-8080-exec-4 | OrServerWebExchangeMatcher:57 |  | Trying to match using PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/login', method=POST}
2024-01-03 11:30:35.639 | DEBUG | http-nio-8080-exec-4 | PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher:82 |  | Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'POST /login'
2024-01-03 11:30:35.639 | DEBUG | http-nio-8080-exec-4 | OrServerWebExchangeMatcher:62 |  | No matches found
2024-01-03 11:30:35.639 | DEBUG | http-nio-8080-exec-4 | OrServerWebExchangeMatcher:57 |  | Trying to match using PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/login', method=GET}
2024-01-03 11:30:35.640 | DEBUG | http-nio-8080-exec-4 | PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher:100 |  | Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/login'
2024-01-03 11:30:35.640 | DEBUG | http-nio-8080-exec-4 | OrServerWebExchangeMatcher:62 |  | matched
```

I'm exhausted because I've tested probably 20 piece of code !!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem after a lot of debugging & investigations.
Problem comes from this dependency inside my pom.
In fact I had a spring project to act as a web server and also as an API Gateway.
But they are not compliant together. Kind of conflicts between webflux from spring cloud starter gateway and my spring starter web.
I removed it and now all pieces of code I've tested work.
I created another project only acting as API gateway

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId> 
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId> 
   <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```